# How to get the oauth refresh token?

Tags: c#, oauth, oauth-2.0, access-token

I have a web app which utlizes Oauth and is unable to reuse the authToken due to the error below.

```
{"AADSTS70002: Error validating credentials. AADSTS54005: OAuth2 Authorization 
code was already redeemed, please retry with a new valid code or use an 
existing refresh token.\r\nTrace ID: 30c342a7-f16a-4a05-a4a8- 
c7ee2c722300\r\nCorrelation ID: 3a5c99d1-ca1c-4cd7-bd36- 
cce721bf05b6\r\nTimestamp: 2018-11-21 00:26:18Z"}
```

I'm told this is a know issue/update [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/4192e141-309a-4dd6-a5c9-f1a8ce32f4ca/aadsts54005-oauth2-authorization-code-was-already-redeemed?forum=WindowsAzureAD%20) and [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/fundamentals/whats-new#change-notice-authorization-codes-will-no-longer-be-available-for-reuse). 
...okay, fine so now I'm trying to get the refresh token so I can regenerate my access token but I'm having trouble getting something to work.

I have tried the ones below:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bingads/shopping-content/code-example-authentication-oauth - this one does not seem to work and throws an exception when I try to get the accesstoken or refresh token. stating that one or more errors have occured.

https://auth0.com/docs/api/authentication#authorization-code-pkce- - but does not return the refresh token. Could this be because I don't have the code_verifier? If so, how would I get that?

[Authorization Code (PKCE) Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UEdEF.png)

Below is a code sample which I am using - problem here is that I can only use this once and once It has been redemed I cannot retrive it silently as it no longer exists in the cache.

```
ClientCredential clientcred = new ClientCredential(Constants.ClientId, Constants.AppKey);

 TokenCache TC = new TokenCache();

 AuthenticationContext AC = new AuthenticationContext(Constants.Authority, TC);
 //Set token from authentication result
 AuthenticationResult authenticationResult = await AC.AcquireTokenByAuthorizationCodeAsync(
            Constants.Code,
 new Uri(Constants.postLogoutRedirectUri + "Index"), clientcred);

 return authenticationResult.AccessToken;
```

Comment: what auth server are you connecting to?

Comment: Did you find the fix for this? I have same issue.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call OAuth2 authorize endpoint with *offline_access* scope to get refresh token.

You should call AcquireTokenByAuthorizationCodeAsync only once when you receive authorization code and should not use the result. [azure ad sample](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapp-webapi-openidconnect/blob/3d3aa98272375cd8a749a1262f056b65184194d6/TodoListWebApp/App_Start/Startup.Auth.cs#L104)

You need to call AcquireTokenSilently when you want to get access token. [azure ad sample](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapp-webapi-openidconnect/blob/3d3aa98272375cd8a749a1262f056b65184194d6/TodoListWebApp/Controllers/TodoListController.cs#L58)

This [azure ad sample](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapp-webapi-openidconnect/blob/master/TodoListWebApp/Utils/NaiveSessionCache.cs) use a TokenCache implementation by user id.

**Authorize request**
[image: Authorize request]

**Token request**
[image: Token request]

Good luck!

Comment: Your token screenshot looks just like the screenshot I had linked in my description. I’m am however, missing the reply uri. Is that the difference between getting the refresh token and not getting it?

Comment: The offline_access into authorize request.