# "AADSTS54005: OAuth2 Authorization code was already redeemed, please retry with a new valid code or use an existing refresh token" Az API Management

Tags: oauth-2.0, azure-api-management

I am trying to obtain an authorization token to consume a published API in Azure API Management, for which I am performing the following steps:

1. Call the authorization URL as follows:

https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/authorize?
client_id=<CLIENT_ID>
&response_type=code
&response_mode=query
&redirect_uri=<REDIRECT_URI>
&scope=SCOPE

2. **Immediately after**, I call the following URL with the obtained authorization code and other parameters in the body and to send them as form-data:

POST https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/token

client_id=<CLIENT_ID>
scope=SCOPE
grant_type=authorization_code
client_secret=<CLIENT_SECRET>
code=<AUTHORIZATION_CODE_PREVIOUS_STEP>

As a result, I get the following error and cannot continue:

{
"error": "invalid_grant",
"error_description": "AADSTS54005: OAuth2 Authorization code was already redeemed, please retry with a new valid code or use an existing refresh token.\r\nTrace ID: f0264d85-2f41-4009-9e8e-1a211209e100\r\nCorrelation ID: c6b15ffb-82e8-49aa-941f-6c85be4d9601\r\nTimestamp: 2022-01-18 15:06:55Z",
"error_codes": [
54005
],
"timestamp": "2022-01-18 15:06:55Z",
"trace_id": "f0264d85-2f41-4009-9e8e-1a211209e100",
"correlation_id": "c6b15ffb-82e8-49aa-941f-6c85be4d9601"
}

I understand that the authorization code is for one use only but, in my case, on the first attempt I get this error.

Any help is appreciated

Comment: You can refer to similar issues [OAuth2 Authorization code was already redeemed](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/311300/oauth2-authorization-code-was-already-redeemed.html), [Unable to retrieve access token from authorisation code for Azure app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60452781/unable-to-retrieve-access-token-from-authorisation-code-for-azure-app) and [How to get the oauth refresh token?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53548543/how-to-get-the-oauth-refresh-token)